# sending json data to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have some json data which i want to send to mongodb using kafka consumer in nodejs. I want different collection for each part of the JSON data. How do i do that? Any help would be appreciated

```
[
  {
    "`Bin_details`": {
      "Device_ID": "1"
    },
    "Device_Status": {
      "Filled_status": "0.097",
      "TimeStamp": "15:56:23"
    },
    "date": "15-6-2021"
  },
  {
    "Bin_details": {
      "Device_ID": "2"
    },
    "Device_Status": {
      "Filled_status": "0.086",
      "TimeStamp": "15:56:23"
    },
    "date": "15-6-2021"
  },
  {
    "Bin_details": {
      "Device_ID": "3"
    },
    "Device_Status": {
      "Filled_status": "0.087",
      "TimeStamp": "15:56:23"
    },
    "date": "15-6-2021"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new collection with a loop like this:

```
const jsonData = [
  {
    "`Bin_details`": {
      "Device_ID": "1"
    },
    "Device_Status": {
      "Filled_status": "0.097",
      "TimeStamp": "15:56:23"
    },
    "date": "15-6-2021"
  },
  {
    "Bin_details": {
      "Device_ID": "2"
    },
    "Device_Status": {
      "Filled_status": "0.086",
      "TimeStamp": "15:56:23"
    },
    "date": "15-6-2021"
  },
  {
    "Bin_details": {
      "Device_ID": "3"
    },
    "Device_Status": {
      "Filled_status": "0.087",
      "TimeStamp": "15:56:23"
    },
    "date": "15-6-2021"
  }
];

// DB Setup
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const client = new MongoClient(DB_CONNECTION_STRING, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
await client.connect();
const db = await client.db();

// Loop to create collections
let index = 0;
for(let eachData of jsonData){
    const collectionName = `Collection-${index}`
    await db.createCollection(collectionName);
    index++;
}
```